# What does "jusqu'à trois trimestres à la fois" mean ?

Tags: sens, expressions, vocabulaire

La phrase est : "Ces bourses sont attribuées jusqu'à trois trimestres à la fois". Quel est son sens ?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [*Larousse.fr* definition of "trimestre"](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/trimestre/79677) quoted below, I think that "trois trimestres" in your context is referring to the three, 3-month-long terms/divisions of a typical nine-month-long French academic year:

> [trimestre =] Chacune des trois divisions de l'année scolaire française
>   (de septembre à juillet) équivalant approximativement à trois mois et
>   séparée par des vacances.

With this interpretation of "trimestre" in mind, "jusqu'à trois trimestres à la fois" could be replaced with "jusqu'à une année [scolaire] à la fois" in your sentence, which I believe could be rendered in English as "**for up to** [a maximum of] one [school/academic] year **at a time**" as it is used to describe [these nursing scholarships](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS807US807&biw=1346&bih=589&sxsrf=ACYBGNTh9dEzOltWOwzWfchcJfJ0uDtk7g%3A1570223823785&ei=z7aXXc29L9Hw9AOz6obgCg&q=%22Scholarships+are+awarded+for+up+to+one+year+at+a+time%22&oq=%22Scholarships+are+awarded+for+up+to+one+year+at+a+time%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...24058.36499..41493...0.0..0.528.5447.2-9j4j2j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......33i10.MZJzJFMLrXs&ved=0ahUKEwiN4e_Jw4PlAhVROH0KHTO1AawQ4dUDCAs):

> [These] Scholarships are awarded for up to [a maximum of] one year **at a time** [with the possibility of renewal].

Answer (score 2):

It means "in a row".

- Those scholarship are granted up to three quarters in a row.

It might also mean "in one single attribution".

- Those scholarships are granted by a maximum of three quarters in a single attribution.